# Why this React return code is invalid? (Conditional rendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to understand why the compiled version of this code is invalid

```
<Fragment>
  {listData.list.description && (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: list.description }} />
      {hasTopCollection && <ImageAttribution />}
    </div> 
       // ^ ) expected
    {list.listOptions.brandHeaderType === 20 && <SomeComponent />}
 // ^ Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
  )}
</Fragment>
```

I had this `listData.list.description && <Description>` component in a parent component, but now I want to move this logic into the actual `<Description>` component.

So before this was like this:

```
<Fragment>
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: list.description }} />
      {hasTopCollection && <ImageAttribution />}
    </div>
    {list.listOptions.brandHeaderType === 20 && <SomeComponent />}
</Fragment>
```

Comment: @DedaDev actually the fragment is used to group more than one component

Comment: you are right actually.

Comment: I think it is the double curly, you cant have curly inside curly, brackets behave as a new component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Fragment>` now only has one child, so it isn't really needed.  However, inside the parentheses you have two things.  And parentheses alone aren't sufficient to group children, so a `<Fragment>` can be used there in their place:

```
{listData.list.description &&
  <Fragment>
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: list.description }} />
      {hasTopCollection && <ImageAttribution />}
    </div> 
    {list.listOptions.brandHeaderType === 20 && <SomeComponent />}
  </Fragment>}
```